# Ram and CPU bar like Ubutuntu 10 for Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, memory, cpu-usage, monitoring

Anyone knows these little graphs wich shows the load of the Ram and any single core. I love these because they are so smart! Gadgets are cool but not very smart because I have to switch to the Desktop to see the usage. Do anyone know something very similar for windows? It would help a lot!

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Explorer from SysInternals (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can show a number of graphs when minimised to the task tray.

It can also replace Windows Task Manager and it provides a lot more invaluable information.

Comment: Sorry, I inadvertently pasted the wrong link, and you read my reply before I corrected it.

Comment: cool perfect! exactly what i was looking.